# Regex matching strings not starting with a caret

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

Trying to parse some formulas in .NET and having trouble creating a regex match for a string that does NOT start with a caret.  The regex is intended to match all addition or subtraction clauses and their operands.  For example, finding the addition clauses in the following formula:

```
((a+b)*100)^c+d
```

using `\w[\+\-]\w`

matches both

```
a+b
c+d
```

but I need it to exclude `c+d` because it follows the caret

I tried using:

`(?!^)\w[\+\-]\w` which matches both `a+b` and `c+d`

`[^\^]\w[\+\-]\w` which matches `(a+b`

I need to match only `a+b`.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to match c+d or a+b? It is not clear.

Comment: You're looking for the negative lookbehind `(?<!\^)\w[+-]\w`. Also, you don't need to escape the characters in the set (`-` only if there's a character preceding and following it)

Comment: Can't you just replace `\^.*` with an empty string? Like this **[example](https://regex101.com/r/Qlx1Kl/1)** and then use a regex to match what you want after cleaning the text

Comment: @FedericoPiazza what if the OP has something like `2^c+d(a+b)^c+d`?

Comment: @ctwheels well, honestly this is unclear to me, I understand he does not want anything after `^` so I think he would want just `2`.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza it is unclear and possibly. I understood it as he doesn't want to catch `^\w[+-]\w`

Comment: ctwheels:  I think you are on the right direction with the negative lookbehind, but it doesn't work in all cases.  If the formula has variables of 2 or more characters, such as ((ae+brr)*100)^ae+d/(((ac+br)*100)^c+d), it does not work.

Comment: It is also not going to work if you have `((a+b)*100)^(c+d)`. You need to specific more precisely what you do/don't want to give some more examples. Also (pedantic), your string doesn't start with a caret, it starts with `(`. You are looking for a substring, but it isn't clear what patterns are okay? Perhaps this is an XY Problem - what are you really trying to accomplish?